# changed hirerchy of files and tried to adjust dependencies but make command still doesnt work

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

All of my files were on the same folder and it all worked great, now i organized it as i think would be correct but now i cant finish the compilation

```
this is the tree:
├── assembler.c
├── assembler_utils
│   ├── assembler_utils.c
│   ├── assembler_utils.h
├── error_handler
│   ├── error_handler.c
│   ├── error_handler.h
├── file_utils
│   ├── file_utils.c
│   ├── file_utils.h
├── first
│   ├── first_pass.c
│   ├── first_pass.h
├── globals.h
├── in_utils
│   ├── input_utils.c
│   ├── input_utils.h
├── makefile
├── management
│   ├── table_management.c
│   ├── table_management.h
├── pre
│   ├── pre_assembler.c
│   ├── pre_assembler.h
└── sec
    ├── second_pass.c
    ├── second_pass.h
```

i changed all of the includes on my files to look like this(example):
previously:
`#include "pre_assembler.h"`
now:
`#inclue "../pre/pre_assembler.h"`     (.. - to go back one directory and then to the proper one)

i ran the command to get the proper compilation command:
`gcc -MM assembler.c assembler_utils/assembler_utils.c error_handler/error_handler.c file_utils/file_utils.c first/first_pass.c in_utils/input_utils.c management/table_management.c pre/pre_assembler.c sec/second_pass.c`

and this is how the makefile looks:

```
CC = gcc
EXEC = assembler
OBJS = assembler.o assembler_utils/assembler_utils.o error_handler/error_handler.o file_utils/file_utils.o first/first_pass.o in_utils/input_utils.o pre/pre_assembler.o sec/second_pass.o management/table_management.o
COMP_FLAG = -ansi -Wall -pedantic
DEBUG_FLAG = -g

$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(COMP_FLAG) $(DEBUG_FLAG) $(OBJS) -o $@ -lm

assembler.o: assembler.c pre/pre_assembler.h \
 management/table_management.h globals.h first/first_pass.h \
 sec/second_pass.h file_utils/file_utils.h in_utils/input_utils.h
    $(CC) $(COMP_FLAG) $(DEBUG_FLAG) -c assembler.c -o assembler.o -lm

assembler_utils/assembler_utils.o: assembler_utils/assembler_utils.c \
 assembler_utils/assembler_utils.h globals.h
    $(CC) $(COMP_FLAG) $(DEBUG_FLAG) -c $< -o $@

error_handler/error_handler.o: error_handler/error_handler.c \
 error_handler/error_handler.h globals.h
    $(CC) $(COMP_FLAG) $(DEBUG_FLAG) -c $< -o $@

file_utils/file_utils.o: file_utils/file_utils.c \
 file_utils/file_utils.h globals.h management/table_management.h
    $(CC) $(COMP_FLAG) $(DEBUG_FLAG) -c $< -o $@

first/first_pass.o: first/first_pass.c first/first_pass.h \
 first/../globals.h management/table_management.h \
 in_utils/input_utils.h assembler_utils/assembler_utils.h
    $(CC) $(COMP_FLAG) $(DEBUG_FLAG) -c $< -o $@

in_utils/input_utils.o: in_utils/input_utils.c in_utils/input_utils.h \
 error_handler/error_handler.h globals.h
    $(CC) $(COMP_FLAG) $(DEBUG_FLAG) -c $< -o $@

pre/pre_assembler.o: pre/pre_assembler.c pre/pre_assembler.h \
 management/table_management.h globals.h in_utils/input_utils.h \
 file_utils/file_utils.h error_handler/error_handler.h \
 assembler_utils/assembler_utils.h
    $(CC) $(COMP_FLAG) $(DEBUG_FLAG) -c $< -o $@

sec/second_pass.o: sec/second_pass.c sec/second_pass.h \
 management/table_management.h globals.h in_utils/input_utils.h \
 error_handler/error_handler.h assembler_utils/assembler_utils.h
    $(CC) $(COMP_FLAG) $(DEBUG_FLAG) -c $< -o $@

management/table_management.o: management/table_management.c \
 management/table_management.h globals.h
    $(CC) $(COMP_FLAG) $(DEBUG_FLAG) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    -rm $(EXEC) $(OBJS)
```

I get issues where it claims that i have multiple definitions of the same function, but it points to the first place (for example):

```
/usr/bin/ld: first/first_pass.o: in function `is_valid_symbol_macro_name':
{path}/first/../assembler_utils/assembler_utils.c:50: multiple definition of `is_valid_symbol_macro_name'; {path}/assembler_utils/assembler_utils.c:50: first defined here
```

I tried to consult with chatGPT on the makefile and my files since i dont see any issue there but hes no assisting that much

Comment: Your organization is not *wrong*, but I wouldn't account it any more correct than having all the files in the same directory.  Splitting each (source, header) pair into its own subdirectory is very *unusual*, however, and that unnecessary complication will require additional unnecessary complication in your build system, your source files, or both.  I would not have performed such a reorganization on my own project.

Comment: "*this is how the makefile looks*" -- that is C source code, not makefile contents.  And we probably do need the makefile to determine what may be going wrong in your build.

Comment: However, the `make` error message you show does seem to indicate that you're building at least one C source twice.

Comment: @JohnBollinger you're correct i copied a wrong file i fixed it now :)

Comment: Look for a place where you mistakenly `#include "../assembler_utils/assembler_utils.c"` instead of `#include "../assembler_utils/assembler_utils.h"`.  Check files `first/first_pass.c` and `first/first_pass.h` first.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That worked! thanks!! how can i mark your comment as an answer?

Comment: You cannot mark my comment as an answer or accept it, but I have written an expanded version as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that you have two definitions of the same function.  One source location given seems pretty normal: `{path}/assembler_utils/assembler_utils.c:50`.  But the other is a bit surprising: `{path}/first/../assembler_utils/assembler_utils.c:50`.

Note in particular that those seem to contain two different paths to the same file.  I don't see anything in the makefile that would explain multiple compilation of the same file, but you could get that effect by both compiling a file and `#include`ing it in a separate file that you also compile.  Since you had to modify your `#include` statements in the course of your reorganization, it seems likely that you did so incorrectly in at least one place.

Look for a place where you mistakenly `#include "../assembler_utils/assembler_utils.c"` instead of `#include "../assembler_utils/assembler_utils.h"`.  Based on the form of the second path given in the error message, you'll probably find the error in `first/first_pass.c` and / or `first/first_pass.h`